# How can I reload tableview within my TableViewController within button action?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Currently I have the following code which saves an object however I am wanting to update/reload the tableview. The button isn't attached to a cell/row it's top right within my navigation controller (plus icon)

Note: Everything is happening within the same scene therefore any events attached to segue where I could reload table data is out of the question.

```
    @IBAction func addWeek (sender: UIButton){

    let newnumber:Int = routineWeeks.count + 1

    // save data using cor data managed object context
    if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext {
        week = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Weeks", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! Weeks

        week.weekNumber = newnumber

        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return
        }
    }

    //currently not reloading table with new data
    tableView.reloadData()

    //print information in console

    print("end of save function, dismiss controller")

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Week \(routineWeeks[indexPath.row].weekNumber)"

    return cell
}
```

**UPDATE**
Thanks Stackoverflow community for pointing me in the right direction.

```
routineWeeks.append(week)
print("this is a new week:\(week)")
tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Can you link the code of your delegate function of your `tableView` ? And what is populating your `tableView` ?

Comment: To me it looks like it should reload the data. Have you tried putting a breakpoint in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath()`? Can you paste the code where you're getting the data from core data?

Comment: @Andrej using core data correct

Comment: @Chajmz using core data added some more code to question to hopefully give you a clearer picture

Comment: can you check if your tableview is nil when you call reload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
routineWeeks.append(week)
print("this is a new week:\(week)")
tableView.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to never add "week" to routineWeeks.

EDIT :
You should reload the datas in routineWeeks (from CoreData) right before your tableView.reloadData.

Comment: It gets added to core data though, when I close the app and re open it the new row/cell has been added.

Comment: Then, reload routineWeeks with the coreData datas.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it will help you or not but I had the same problems and I added [Refresher](https://github.com/jcavar/refresher) (to add "Pull To Refresh" function)

In my class :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Pull to refresh - DEBUT
        tableFiches.addPullToRefreshWithAction {
            NSOperationQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
                //sleep(1)
                NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
                    self.loadMyData() // My func here to load data
                    self.tableFiches.stopPullToRefresh()
                }
            }
        }
        // Pull to refresh - FIN

    }

func loadMyData(){
   // request here
   let recupJSON = JSON(value) // my data
   if let resData = recupJSON["Data"].arrayObject {
                        //print("OK2")
   self.ArrayFiches = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]] // Attribute  json ==> ArrayFiches
   }
  if self.ArrayFiches.count > 0 {
    self.tableFiches.reloadData()
  }
}
```

And when I want reload my data, I use :

```
tableFiches.startPullToRefresh()
```

And it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating routineWeeks array. Update it with your new data before reloading the tableView.